# How to declare two different static variables? (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-variables

EDIT: declaring them private was a typo, I fixed it:

Relating to another question, if I declared a static variable in a class, then derived a class from that, is there any way to declare the static variable as individual per each class.  Ie:

```
class A:
{
public:
static int x;
};
class B:A
{
public:
const static int x;
};
```

does that define TWO DIFFERENT static variables `x`, one for A and one for B, or will I get an error for redefining `x`, and if I do get an error, how do a I create two seperate static variables?

Comment: lol I thought this question would have been answered faster and sooner by the compiler than any of us here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using static variables, it might be a good idea to refer to them explicitly:

```
public class B:A
{
  public const static int x;
  public int foo()
  {
    return B::x;
  }
}
```

That way, even if the class "above" yours in the hierarchy decides to create a similarly-named member, it won't break your code.  Likewise, I usually try to us the `this` keyword when accessing normal member fields.

**Updated** to use C++ syntax.

Comment: To note, this is Java syntax. To do the same kind of explicit reference in C++, you need to use the scoping operator, e.g. B::x

Comment: Well, the rest of the surrounding code still isn't legal C++, but I think the questioner will be able to translate assuming he is sufficiently familiar with C++. :)

Answer (score 1):

That creates two separate static variables.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have implicitly declared these private:

```
class A:
{
  private:
  static int x;
};
class B:A
{
  private:
  const static int x;
};
```

Which means the variables are not in competition with each other.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, that creates two separate variables :

```
A::x;

// and 

B::x;
```

In fact if you try to use just 'x' in a method of B, only the closer scope definition will be used until you are more precise :

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
static int x;

public:
    A() { x = 7; }
};

int A::x = 22;

class B:A
{
static const int x = 42;

public:

    int a_x() const { return A::x; }
    int b_x() const { return B::x; }
    int my_x() const { return x; } // here we get the more local variable, that is B::x.
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    std::cout << "A::x = " << b.a_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B::x = " << b.b_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b's x = " << b.my_x() << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
A::x = 7
B::x = 42
b's x = 42
```

Someone mentioned that accessibility might limit accessibility : making the base variable private will not make it accessible to the child class. 
However, if the variable have to be protected or public, use an explicit access method or rely on the local scope rule I just demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static variable that is individual to each class that uses A - you can use a template class.
For e.g.

```
template<class T> struct A
{
   A() { ++s_var; }
   static int s_var;
};

template<class T> int A<T>::s_var;

stuct B :A<B> {
  B() { ++s_var; }  // this is a different s_var than the one used by 'C' below
};

struct C : A<C> {
  C() { ++s_var; } // this is a different s_var than the one used by 'B'
};
```